# How to read from a DBF file on a 64bit OS using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, dbf

Using Delphi, now that the Microsoft Jet Driver is no longer supported on 64bit operating systems, what would be the best way to read from a DBF/DBase file?

Comment: As simple as the dbf format is, getting an open source version of a library and compiling it for your platform seems a pretty good option

Comment: Any DBX drivers for DBF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [TDbf](http://tdbf.sourceforge.net/) - freeware quite robust solution
- [Advantage Database](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/advantagedatabaseserver) - commercial DBF solution
- [Apollo DB Engine](http://www.vistasoftware.com/apollo_vcl.asp) - another commercial DBF solution

Comment: Advantage Local Client (up to 5 users) is free, even for commercial use. It supports all versions of Delphi, and their TDataSet descendant components work with all of Delphi's data-aware controls.

Comment: Since you only want to read, I'd definitely use TDbf! :-) It can write too, btw.